# Декодировка текста

Tags: javascript, html

Как раскодировать текст вида:

```
&#1058;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;
```

. Что это вообще за код? Это достается из файла htm, который читается xls файлом выводящий русские буквы. В htm файле этот текст в виде того что я привел в качестве примера.
Я нашел как закодировать русский текст чтобы потом его Excel увидел, а вот как раскодировать его после? 
Кодирую так:

```
document.write(
  '<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,',
  encodeURIComponent('\ufeff' + contents2+" Слово "+contents3), //utf8 bom(чтоб     эксель понял кодировку) + строка 
'" download="' + name + '.htm">' + name + '</a>');
```

Comment: Это [HTML-мнемоники](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML).

Comment: Хорошо! Есть способ декодировать в русские символы?

Comment: `'\ufeff'` - это НЕ utf8.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я брал код с сайта,комментарии не мои.

Comment: Так думать надо, когда с сайта берёшь.

Comment: Так, если б подумав можно было все узнать и все выучить, я бы не спрашивал тут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [HTML-мнемоники](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML).
Пример кодирования и декодирования:

```js
(function(window){
 window.htmlentities = {
  /**
   * Converts a string to its html characters completely.
   *
   * @param {String} str String with unescaped HTML characters
   **/
  encode : function(str) {
   var buf = [];
   
   for (var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
   }
   
   return buf.join('');
  },
  /**
   * Converts an html characterSet into its original character.
   *
   * @param {String} str htmlSet entities
   **/
  decode : function(str) {
   return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
   });
  }
 };
})(window);

let str = '&#1058;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;';
let _str = htmlentities.decode(str);

console.info("Encoded string: " + str);  // Encoded string: &#1058;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;
console.info("Decoded string: " + _str); // Decoded string: Текст
```

Comment: УОУ!)) Работает, Пасибо!) Приятно когда с паста все запускается как надо!)